# Laravel S3 image upload creates a folder with the filename automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm using Laravel 5.4.*. I've this simple code in a helper file to upload images/gif in S3 bucket under a folder named say "instant_gifs/". The code is below:

```
if ( !function_exists('uploadFile') ) {

function uploadFile($fileContent, $fileName, $size='full', $disk='s3')
{
    $rv = '';
    if( empty($fileContent) ) {
        return $rv;
    }

    if($size == 'full') {
        dump($fileName);

        $path = Storage::disk($disk)->put(
                    $fileName,
                    $fileContent,
                    'public'
                );
    }

    if ( $path ) {
        $rv = $fileName;
    }

    return $rv;
}

}
```

From the controller, I'm calling the helper method as below:

```
$file = $request->gif;
$file_name = 'instant_gifs/' . $user_id . '_' . time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$result = uploadFile($file, $file_name);
```

In the the $fileName parameter of the helper method, I'm providing the fileName as for example in this format:

> "instant_gifs/83_1518596022_giphy.gif"

but after the upload, I see that the file gets stored under this folder

> "vvstorage/instant_gifs/83_1518596022_giphy.gif/CRm1o1YEcvX3fAulDeDfwT7DIMCxOKG8WFGcA3lB.gif"

with a random file name

> CRm1o1YEcvX3fAulDeDfwT7DIMCxOKG8WFGcA3lB.gif

Whereas, according to the code, it should get stored in this path:

> "vvstorage/instant_gifs/83_1518596022_giphy.gif"

Doesn't get any explanation why this is happening. Any clue will be appreciated.

**BucketName = vvstorage 

 Folder I'm mimicking  = instant_gifs**

Comment: check this for better solution:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105104/how-to-fix-upload-image-to-s3-using-laravel/61826028#61826028

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After some research & testing, found the issue. `put()` method expects the 2nd parameter as the file contents or stream not the file object. In my code, I was sending the file as `$file = $request->gif;` or `$file = $request->file('gif');` hoping that Storage class will implicitly get the file contents. But to get the expected result, I needed to call the helper method from the controller as below. Notice the **file_get_contents()** part.

```
$file = $request->gif;
$file_name = 'instant_gifs/' . $user_id . '_' . time() . '_' . $file>getClientOriginalName();
$result = uploadFile( file_get_contents($file), $file_name );
```

Now, I got the image correctly stored under the correct path for example in `/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg`.

Now, let me compare/summarize the available methods for achieving the same result:

1) [put()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_put):

```
 $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put(
                    '/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg', #$path
                    file_get_contents($request->file('gif')), #$fileContent
                   'public' #$visibility
```

Got it stored in `/vvstorage/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg`

2) [putFileAs()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_putFileAs): To achieve the same thing with`putFileAs()`, I needed to write it as below. 1st parameter expects the directory name, I left it blank as I'm mimicking the directory name in s3 through the filename.

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs(
                '', ## 1st parameter expects directory name, I left it blank as I'm mimicking the directory name through the filename
                '/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg',
                $request->file('gif'), ## 3rd parameter file resource
                ['visibility' => 'public'] #$options
            );
```

Got it stored in `/vvstorage/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg`

3) [storeAs()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_storeAs):

```
$path = $request->file('gif')->storeAs(
             '', #$path
             '/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg', #$fileName
             ['disk'=>'s3', 'visibility'=>'public'] #$options
             );
```

Got it stored in `/vvstorage/instant_gifs/9_1518633281_IMG_7491.jpg`

**Extras::** 
4) For storing Thumbnails through `put()`. Example of stream() ...

```
$imgThumb = Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(300, 300)->stream(); ##create thumbnail
        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put(
                    'profilethumbs/' . $imgName,
                    $imgThumb->__toString(),
                    'public'
                );
```

Hope that it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Why is there `vvstorage` in the url?

It is appending that route because your `root` folder inside of your `configuration` for `S3` is set as `vvstorage`, so whenever you upload to `S3` all files will be prepended with `vvstorage`.

2.) Why random name even when you passed the name of the file?

Because when using `put` the file will get a `unique ID` generated and set as it's file name so no matter what you pass, it won't save the file under the name you wanted. But if you use `putFileAs` then you can override the default behaviour of `put` and pass a name of the file.

Hope this clarifies it

Comment: 1) "vvstorage" is the main Bucket, it'll be always in the file URL. No problem with that.

2) You might have confused `put` with `putFile` method. `putFile` will automatically generate unique filename. `put` method is supposed to store the file in the given path in the disk [Laravel Storing Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem).

The same code with `put` worked while uploading profile images but not working in the files upload section for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: I said `putFileAs` not `putFile`

Comment: `Put` should work too as I'm providing a filePath to store. BTW, I tried with `putFileAs` in the above uploadFile code. 

`$path = Storage::disk($disk)->putFileAs(
                        'instant_gifs/9_1518602282_IMG_9594.jpg',
                        $fileContent,
                        'public'
              );`

It now get stored in this path `instant_gifs/9_1518602282_IMG_9594.jpg/public`, with the image name "public". 

May be something to deal with the Bucket Access Policy.

Comment: Might be, but still you will be able to access it with the original name, no matter under what name the storage saved it